# The relation between the spring constant and its radius

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, spring, elasticity, stress-strain

I've observed that the spring constant of a spring with a smaller radius is higher than that of a spring with a larger even though they are made of the same material , their thickness and all other factors are same but the radius. Does this mean that the spring constant of a spring made of a given substance is not its property and is there a relation that governs such behaviour of a spring?

Comment: Personally I visualise a single turn of the spring stretching the same amount for both radius sizes. The amount of tension has to be spread evenly through the length of the turn. The turn with the smaller radius would see the larger tension per unit length of the turn, as there is less length of the smaller radius than the larger radius. Assuming that the pulling force of the spring is derived from the cross sectional restoring strain of the wire, when the smaller radius turn is stretched more than the larger radius, it responds by having a stronger restoring force.

Comment: The analysis of a spiral spring is dealt with in detail in older textbooks on the “Properties of Matter” such as those by Champion and Davy (page 62-64) which is available as an ebook at [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.261133/page/n74) and by Newman and Searle.

Comment: See Faupel, J. H. and Fisher, F. E. Engineering Design —A Synthesis of Stress Analysis and Materials Engineering, 2nd Ed. 1981, Wiley Interscience, New York, NY. for a detailed mechanical analysis of spring deformation, which includes the effects of design parameters such as radius, wire diameter, material, and helix angle on the overall spring constant.

Answer (score 1):

The stretching of a helical spring involves two types of deformation...

1. Torsion, that is twisting, of the wire of which the spring is made.
2. Bending of the wire.

To visualise these, think about a small, almost straight, piece of the wire and the stresses it is under.

I believe that, usually, 2 is a considerably smaller effect than 1, so we'll forget about 2.

For a wire in equilibrium, clamped at one end and subjected to a given twisting torque about its central axis at the other end (so an equal and opposite torque will arise at the clamped end), the angle of twist between top and bottom is proportional to the length of the wire (equal segments of wire will twist equal amounts). So for a spring of the same axial length but larger diameter, the length of wire will be larger, so the angle of twist will be larger for a given load and therefore the extension.

The references that Farcher gives in his comment are exactly those that I would give. Champion taught me properties of matter a very long time ago!

Answer (score 0):

Springs response on some outside force indeed depends on its geometry. Of course, on the type of the material also. It depends on the thickness of the spring, number of curves and radius.If you just have a straight wire it would be hard to deform it in the direction that is parallel to it but in the direction vertical to that wire its much easier.So when ju make a spring out of it you are basicaly makin it in such a way to deform it verticaly to the wire direction.Number of curves gives you a total number of parts of wire that you are deforming at the same time. If you have the same spring that means that when you increase the number of curves you get smaller circles so to speak. And all of these give you more resistance.Of course, there is also the effect of the total lenght of the spring...eg if you connect two identical springs you get a new one with more curves BUT now its longer so every curve adds up and you get more deformation for the same force than with just one spring!So, now the spring constant is half of the original one!